# jQuery double object constructor - e.g. $($(this))

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume you have the following code:

```
function name() {
    $(this).css('background', 'red');
}

$('selector1').click(name);

$('selector2').click(function () {
    name.call($(this).parent());
});
```

Now, when the function is called by clicking on 'selector1' `this` is an HTML object and `$(this)` a jQuery object, but if the function is called by clicking on 'selector2' `this` is already a jQuery object so what is `$(this)`?

I know I could do something like `name.call($(this).parent()[0]);` to get an HTML object, but my question is what happens when you do something like `$($(this))` or `$($('selector'))`? What is the result of that and, most impotently, is there any harm in using such a construct?

Comment: A much more popular duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21671105/2157640

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$(this)` when `this` is already a jQuery object creates a copy of the jQuery object.

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> ### Cloning jQuery Objects
>
> When a jQuery object is passed to the `$()` function, a clone of the object is created.
> This new jQuery object references the same DOM elements as the initial one.