# What does $($(this)) mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw some code around the web that uses the following statement

```
if ($($(this)).hasClass("footer_default")) {
      $('#abc')
        .appendTo($(this))
        .toolbar({position: "fixed"});
    }
```

What is the use of `$($(this))` and why is that necessary here?

Comment: Change it to just $(this), It will give the same result

Comment: It means some moron figured he'd be safe and wrap it twice.

Comment: It means - "Who let *that* code get committed?"

Comment: I've also done that way one time and figured $(this) was not working but $($(this)) was working. But forget about that. There might be difference.

Comment: Also note that it is more efficient to assign `$(this)` to a local variable once instead of doing `$(this)` multiple times.

Comment: It also means the guy that wrote this was on a coffee break or something because that's plain pointless!

Comment: It's what we call superstitious code.

Comment: This is like asking what the difference between `(5 + 5)` and `((5 + 5))` is. Plus it's been asked before. No more rep cow for you.

Comment: @AlvinWong is it really more efficient? I've wondered about that. Certainly if `this` is a string, but if it's already a DOM object? I mean, I'm sure it takes a non-zero amount of time/resources to jQuery-ify a DOM node, but is it significant?

Comment: @adeneo What about `var jquery; while (true) { jquery = $(jquery); }`?

Comment: @TurnerHayes - In most cases it's not noticeable, but for complex selectors, it can be quite a bit faster. For `this`, it really makes no difference, as the `this` keyword is interally cached by all modern browsers, and just wrapping a native object in jQuery takes only nanoseconds in newer browsers. In other words, depends on what you're doing! Caching *everything* isn't necessarily a bad idea, but in many cases not neccessary. Should have answered this one, but I figured it would be closed as soon as someone spotted a duplicate, can't believe it got that many upvotes!

Comment: I would have added a couple of try-catches wrapping that too, just in case. Quality gate passed !

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Yes, `$($(this))` is the same as `$(this)`, the `jQuery()` or `$()` function is wonderfully [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).  There is no reason for that particular construction (double wrapping of `this`), however, something I use as a shortcut for grabbing the first element only from a group, which involves similar double wrapping, is

`$($('selector')[0])`

Which amounts to, grab every element that matches `selector`, (which returns a jQuery object), then use `[0]` to grab the first one on the list (which returns a `DOM` object), then wrap it in `$()` again to turn it back into a jQuery object, which this time only contains a single element instead of a collection. It is roughly equivalent to

`document.querySelectorAll('selector')[0];`, which is pretty much
`document.querySelector('selector');`

Comment: Thanks. I think this is what I was looking for. I have seen this throughout the web, now I am more aware of cases related to double wrapping.

Comment: Not exactly idempotence.  Idempotent function always return the same if given the same input, so a pure function is naturally idempotent.  For instance, square(x) is idempotent, but calling square(square(x)) will return a different result to square(x).  In this sense jQuery is rather good at equivocating, rather that idempotence.

Comment: Frankly, I find `$($('selector')[0])` significantly harder to read, compared to `$('selector:eq(0)')` or even `$('selector:first')`, and it will perform worse because of the double "constructor".

Comment: Owen, I believe you are confusing idempotence with injection. Check [Idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) and [Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function). Anyway, $() is not generally idempotent, but if the argument is a jquery object it will return the object it received.

Comment: Or, if you can't tweak the selector like @UweB suggests, you could still use `$('selector').eq(0)`.

Comment: @Owen, I meant idempotent like, f(x)=f(f(x)), and now that you mention it, I believe the SO I am linking to has comments engaging in the same discussion of which definition is "correct," so I suppose it might be more accurate to say that $() is mathematically idempotent?

Comment: I personally prefer `$('selector').eq(0)` if I'm trying to retrieve only the first element as a jquery object

Comment: To get the first element in a jquery collection you can also just use $('selector').get(0)

Comment: I tend to use `$('selector:nth(0)')` for that - less to remember for more flexibility, since `:nth()` can go anywhere in the selector

Comment: @LuisCarvalho, if the argument is a jquery object, then it will return the object it recieved. and since any input will always output a jquery object (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302428/what-does-jquery-actually-return), then it is generally idempotent.

Answer (score 29):

You can wrap `$` as many times as you want, it won't change anything.

If `foo` is a DOM element, `$(foo)` will return the corresponding jQuery object.

If `foo` is a jQuery object, `$(foo)` will return the same object.

That's why `$($(this))` will return exactly the same as `$(this)`.

Answer (score 8):

There is no specific need for double-wrapping and `$($(this))` is exactly the same as `$(this)`.

That said, I once found this double-wrapping in one file in my project, committed by another developer.  Tracking the changes through revision, turned out that it started as `$($(this).find('selector').first())` - that is, the result of some selector was wrapped to create a new object.  Then for whatever reasons, the selector was removed and only the double-wrapping of `this` remained.  Needless to say, on the next commit it was changed to `$(this)`.

Answer (score 6):

As explained before me, `$($(this))` and `$(this)` are absolutely identical. jQuery returns the same jQuery object if you try to wrap it more than once.

Additionally, for performance considerations it is a good practice to reuse jQuery objects - it is quite expensive to create jQuery objects, especially the ones with complex selectors. Example:

```
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.hasClass("footer_default")) {
    $('#abc')
        .appendTo($this)
        .toolbar({position: "fixed"});
}
```

Just google for *'jQuery best practices'* - it will take a 30 min for you to learn these basics and you will use jQuery way more effectively.

Answer (score 3):

There is no meainig of doing that.

The following code return the same:

```
console.log($($(this)).hasClass("footer_default"))
console.log($(this).hasClass("footer_default"))
```

a boolean value depenging on if the selected element has or not the class `footer_default`:

> .hasClass( className )Returns: Boolean

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/aSzFn/

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` and `$($(this))` both return jquery object.

There is no difference between these two.